# Blank space at bottom of ListView not filled

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**EDIT**

I originally thought this issue was related to the search widget and keyboard.

**Original Question**

I added the search widget to my app recently. Now when I land on MainActivity, the view is cut right where the keyboard would pop up. The content scrolls within that smaller box. When I hit the search widget in the action bar, the keyboard pops up and fills the blank space. When I collapse the keyboard, my view is complete and there is no blank space. Check this photo to see what I mean. [image: this photo]

Here are my layouts

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

feed_item.xml (inflates listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/vendorPic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_vendor_pic_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_vendor_pic_height"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeadlineMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />



        <com.example.myapp.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my searchable config xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Let me know if you need more to go on, thanks!!

P.S. min sdk is 12.

**UPDATE**

The problem ended up being that the content didn't really fill the whole screen until the images were loaded from the Volley request. The text content was loaded and set the height of the listview, and subsequently loaded content did not dynamically change the listiview height. In production this won't be a problem probably, but is there a way to make sure that the ListView height can change dynamically?

Comment: Try to save the Search Action as a global variable at onCreateOptionsMenu and after the activity loads call searchAction.setIconified(true). Otherwise try `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` on your activity in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up having nothing to do with the search widget or keyboard. the sizing was coincidental.

The problem lies in the fact that each item in the ListView had an image that was being loaded from the API via volley. the height of the ListView was being set by the content that was loaded first (i.e. text). Once the image loaded, it expanded each item in the list, but did not change the height of the parent ListView. This left the ugly gap at the bottom of the view.

On advice from @mattgmg1990, I changed the height of the ListView to `match_parent` in order to allow for late loading images.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the keyboard is trying to expand when you open the activity. It is strange that it stays blank and doesn't show the actual keyboard, but maybe preventing the keyboard from opening in the beginning will help. Try setting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

in your `<activity>` tag for this Activity in AndroidManfest.xml.

Comment: Hmmm.. unfortunately this did not resolve the problem.

Comment: check my comment on Shade's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and to your list view("id"),try adding

```
android:alignParentBottom:"true"
```

Comment: Can you clarify where to add `alignParentBottom`? My xml layout doesn't like that line...

Comment: Oh sorry.. Just noticed it's a linear layout... Change the parent layout of your list view to relative layout and add it there... Also.. Whenever u have keyboard issues.. Try using relative layouts.. Gives you a bit more control over things..

Comment: And based on what @mattgmg1990 also said.. Try giving focus to ur parent layout on screen load instead of a text box... Ie.. Put a layout.requestFocus()  for the list view on activity load..

Comment: Wow, I feel a little stupid here. The problem ended up being the fact that the content really didn't fill the screen until my images were loaded by Volley. The listview populated and set the height based on the existing content. The size image content just happened to be close to the size of the keyboard. After it loaded, the listview height doesn't respond.

Comment: @settheline Just set the ListView height to match the parent of the containing layout so that it will fill the available space. If there aren't enough items in the list until the images load, it will probably just not fill the space and end up looking about the same. But when the items take up more space, everything will look how you want it and fill to the bottom. Also, glad to hear you found the answer! Maybe just answer your own question here and mark it as accepted so others can clearly see what happened.